# How do I get JavaScript source maps working on Android with Capacitor, OpenUI5 and ui5-cli?

Tags: javascript, android, sapui5, capacitor

I am using [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) (version 5.1.0), [ui5-cli](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/v3/) (version 3.3.1), and OpenUI5 (version 1.108.14) to build a cross-platform Android app.

When the Android app is running on a physical device, I can inspect it using Chrome DevTools and see the output of `console.log()` statements,
but when I click on the source file link to view the JavaScript file that has the `console.log()` statement (i.e. `Page-dbg.controller.js:129`) I get an error that Chrome could not load the content:

```plaintext
Could not load content for http://localhost/resources/com/hypercision/sap/ui/restApp/Login/ServerSelect/Page-dbg.controller.js (Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
```

[image: log statement in the Console tab of Chrome DevTools]

[image: Error stating that source file could not be loaded in Sources tab of Chrome DevTools]

I am thinking this is due to the OpenUI5 [virtual file system "UI5 FS"](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/v3/pages/FileSystem/) that offers an abstraction layer from the physical file system.
My guess is that the URL for the debug source file should be http://localhost/Login/ServerSelect/Page-dbg.controller.js
since the unminified debug file is located at the following path in the Android build directory on my machine:

`android/app/src/main/assets/public/Login/ServerSelect/Page-dbg.controller.js`

I am building the OpenUI5 app using the command `ui5 build self-contained -a --clean-dest --dest ./www`, and building/running the Android app with `npx cap run android`.
The latter command inlines the source maps in the minified JavaScript files.

Is there a way to get the source maps to load correctly in Chrome DevTools?

I also tried building the OpenUI5 app using the command `ui5 build -a --clean-dest --dest ./www` and I got the following error when clicking on the source file link in Chrome DevTools:

```plaintext
Could not load content for http://localhost/Login/ServerSelect/Page-dbg.controller.js (Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
```

So that proves my theory to be incorrect because the unminified debug file is still located at the same path in the Android build directory on my machine.

In the meantime, I have found I can use the debug source files in our development builds by adding `data-sap-ui-debug="true"` to where I bootstrap the UI5 application in `index.html`:

```html
<script
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-debug="true"
    data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="true"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
    data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-async="true"
    data-sap-ui-onInit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.hypercision.sap.ui.restApp": "./"}'
    data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted"
></script>
```